# Wordpress Post in Multiple Divs

Tags: wordpress, post, html

Hi I have the need to have 3 separate posts in 3 separate divs.

Like this:

div 1
post content...

div 2
posted content
div

div 3
post content

I wold like the ability to add the posts in the visual/html editor in my dashboard and display this content on the same page in 3 divs. What is the best way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add custom fields to the post type. This will allow you to add any fields you want to the post type and then you can display them in any manner you would like in the output. Take a look at https://github.com/jaredatch/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress for an easy way to do it.

Comment: Thanks so much, This type of plugin works for what I want. Can I do the same in PHP somehow?

Comment: What I listed is a PHP framework for doing what you seek. You can do so yourself using the WordPress http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields and other APIs

Comment: Thnaks this looks like the best solution for me and it works like a charm when I tested it.  thanks for the help